# Couldn't run pyqt5 on python 3.6 64bits on Windows 10 (No anaconda no virtualenv)

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.6

Since none of the proposed answers on other threads relarted to this question worked for me, I open a new very specific thread about this issue.

I have installed a 64bits version of python 3.6 on windows 10 from the main python website. I don't use neither  virtualenv  nor anaconda.
I then installed pyqt5 using pip package installer :

```
pip install pyqt5
```

At this point I expect to be able to do :

```
>>from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File stdin, line 1, in module
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.

The French part, means :  The specified procedure was not found

I do have the python3.dll in the c:/Programs/python36 folder.
I copied it to c:/Programs/python36/scripts folder, and it still doesn't work.

Is there a known issue between python 3.6 on windows and pyqt5?

## Complementary Infos:

My PC is a 64bits PC.
I did install python 64bits from :
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/

Comment: Have you added the python PATH to the environment variables?

Comment: My python is in the path. And It seems that it finds the pyQT5 module. The problem is that somehow, it doesn't find a DLL. I have QT 5.11.1 installed on my PC. But still doesn't work :(

Comment: you could indicate from where you installed python, also if your pc is 32bits or 64bits. You do not need to have Qt installed.

Comment: Which of the installers did you use?

Comment: I used this one: Windows x86-64 executable installer

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for the QT.dll. You need to install QT manually

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-support.html

Comment: I did install QT 5.11.1 on my PC. But nothing did happen.